# How to implement SuperSocket

Tags: sockets, tcp, supersocket.net

I am trying to implement Supersockets - https://supersocket.codeplex.com/ for a project i am working on. I have the a server that uses configuration to run. 
In my project

I have referenced:

```
SuperSocket.Common,
SuperSocket.SocketBase,
SuperSocket.SocketEngine
```

I added the following config section:

```
 <configSections>
    <section name="superSocket" type="SuperSocket.SocketEngine.Configuration.SocketServiceConfig, SuperSocket.SocketEngine" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
    <add key="ServiceName" value="SomeService" />
    </appSettings>
    <superSocket logFactory="ConsoleLogFactory"
              disablePerformanceDataCollector="true"
              maxWorkingThreads="500"
              maxCompletionPortThreads="500"
              minWorkingThreads="5"
              minCompletionPortThreads="5">
    <servers>
      <server name="SomeService"
              serverType="SomeService.Server.SomeService, SomeService"
              ip="192.168.1.107"
              port="4096"
              disableSessionSnapshot="true"
              clearIdleSession="false"
              maxConnectionNumber="10"
              sendWelcome="false">
      </server>
    </servers>
    <logFactories>
      <add name="ConsoleLogFactory"
           type="SuperSocket.SocketBase.Logging.ConsoleLogFactory, SuperSocket.SocketBase" />
    </logFactories>
    </superSocket>
```

I also created the server and session class as follows:

```
 namespace SomeService.Server
    {

    class SomeService: AppServer<SomeServiceSession>
    {

        protected override bool Setup(IRootConfig rootConfig, IServerConfig config)
        {

            return base.Setup(rootConfig, config);
        }

        protected override void OnStartup()
        {
            base.OnStarted();
        }

        protected override void OnStopped()
        {
            base.OnStopped();
        }

    }
    }

    namespace SomeService.Server
    {
    class SomeServiceSession : AppSession<SomeServiceSession>
    {
        protected override void OnSessionStarted()
        {
            // this.Send("Welcome to SuperSocket Telnet Server");
        }

        protected override void HandleUnknownRequest(StringRequestInfo requestInfo)
        {
            this.Send("Unknow request");
        }

        protected override void HandleException(Exception e)
        {
            this.Send("Application error: {0}", e.Message);
        }

        protected override void OnSessionClosed(CloseReason reason)
        {
            //add you logics which will be executed after the session is closed
            base.OnSessionClosed(reason);
        }
    }
    }
```

At this point the Server runs and it listens on a port as intended. Here is a wireshark representation of what i would want to do With SuperSocket http://imgur.com/rxKJbOD.
If you see on the request reply one chuck of the data :

```
.MSH|^~\&|MRI|ABC|||201403251406||QRY|173883426|P|2.1
QRD|201403251406|R|I|xxxxx|||25^RD|AB851656^|MPI
QRF|UPI||||
.
```

is from the client and

```
.MSH|^~\&|MRI|ABC|||201403251406||QRY|173883426|P|2.1
QRD|201403251406|R|I|xxxx|||25^RD|AB851656^|MPI
QRF|UPI||||
MSA|AA|173883426
.
```

is from the server. the response returned varies depending on the request and what is created after the business logic executes (but it is always going to be the same format- HL7 en(dot)wikipedia(dot)org/wiki/Health_Level_7 ). HL7 follows MLLP messaging format where each message begins with a Start Block code (0x0B) and each segment within the message is terminated with a Carriage Return code (0x0D) and each message is terminated by an End Block code (0x1C) followed by a Carriage Return code (0x0D). Once i get the request i have a business logic class that parses out the values, calls a web service gets the data and constructs a the tcp reply. What i would like to know is where in SuperSocket can i have a method or event listener to read the buffer and do my business logic and return the response for the same session. I know that there are concepts like filters and commands in SuperSocket but i haven't been able to figure them out. Any help is greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need additional detail.

Comment: I was able to solve this using the BeginEndMarkReceiveFilter example in http://docs.supersocket.net/v1-6/en-US/The-Built-in-Common-Format-Protocol-Implementation-Templates. The GPS example project under Advanced in the QuickStart project offered by the SuperSocket writer was also extremely useful.